# Sync Gradle Android Studio Failed on SlideDateTimePicker

Tags: android, gradle, datetimepicker

I want to create an EditText that could pick date and time at the same time. I found this [library](https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker/) but I failed build this library. It says

```
Error:(31, 0) Project with path ':slideDateTimePicker' could not be found in project ':app'
```

According to the grade.build file, it looks like we should have this library as a project first. Here is the dependencies that I should add

```
compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')
```

How should I add this library into my project? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add library files to your project directory as well. Also add
this line to settings.gradle:

```
include 'your-library-directory'
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this on your gradle:

`compile 'com.github.jjobes:slideDateTimePicker:1.0.2'`

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches. First approach, if you want to use the library `out-of-the-box` without source code changes. Second, if you want to modify the  source code later on.

1. As dependency on `app` level; add the following line in your build.gradle file:
   `compile 'com.github.jjobes:slideDateTimePicker:1.+'`
2. Add as a `sub-project` to your existing project; add the [slideDateTimePicker](https://github.com/jjobes/SlideDateTimePicker/tree/master/slideDateTimePicker) folder to your projects `root` folder:

   - under `dependencies` on `app` level build.gradle file add:
     `compile project(path: ':slideDateTimePicker')`
   - and in your settings.gradle file add:
     `include ':slideDateTimePicker'`

Answer (score 0):

file-> input modle>SlideDateTimePicker, and then:  project settings-> add modle->choice SlideDateTimePicker.

or

copy SlideDateTimePicker to you project root path. and add compile project(':slideDateTimePicker') in your build.gradle, add include ':slideDateTimePicker' in settings.gradle

Hope this can help you.